# How to make a table only high as it's parent

Tags: css, css-tables

Is it possible to force a table to shrink to the height of it's parent div? The table completely ignores the size of its container, even if I apply 100% height to it.

Comment: Can we see your CSS code ?

Comment: Please post a complete code example. And what knucklehead upvoted this?

Comment: a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would be even more appropriated

Comment: The short answer is NO.  If the parent container does not have a specified height, it will expand to enclose the content (table in this case).  If the parent container has a fixed height, the content could overflow the parent element if the table has many rows.

Answer (score 0):

The height of the table is computed based on the number of rows in the table and so on.

If you specify or inherit a height value for the table, that value is treated as a minimum value.  Therefore, the height of the table may expand, but it will not shrink.

Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#height-layout